# Redirection after successful login operation

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am facing a problem while I am trying to redirecting user to home page after successful login. I am using this example in github.

https://github.com/cornflourblue/react-redux-registration-login-example

In this file, "src/LoginPage/LoginPage.jsx", There is such a part which sends login request in a POST message but I do not see any redirection to home page, just login page. Here is the part:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ submitted: true });
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    if (username && password) {
        dispatch(userActions.login(username, password));
    }
}
```

When I look at the network activity, I see that I receive successful message from response of server. Do I need to add something that does redirection?

Comment: If you look in `userActions` file they use  `dispatch(success(user));
                    history.push('/');` which redirects to home page

Comment: I know but there is no redirection. I have an action object for dispatch method.

Comment: Maybe because you set default page to the login page instead . Try put your home page instead `('/home') `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of problem. If response is successful, something has to be set into localStorage. In private route, it checks whether that thing exists in localStorage. If not, it does not do anything but if it has, it operates the component to be redirected. I forgot to edit this part. That's why, it did not do redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add `Browser Routing` to your project and after a successful login you should redirect to page which you want. For example `to="/Home"`. At first you need something like `isAuth` in your redux reducer. After login submit, if it is successful set this to true and in your `LoginPage` with `mapStateToProps` get this `isAuth` value. Also in your `render()` section use this before your other `jsx` code ->

```
render() {
 let redirect = null;
 if(isAuth == true){
   redirect = <Redirect to="/Home" />;
 }

 return (
    {redirect}
  )
}
```

Comment: I have done with this method before and it works fine also there is nothing wrong with it. Why dont you give it a try? @Eric